# UIScrollView setContentOffset is working on iPhone 6, but not working on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView with paging enabled activated.
I'm trying to scroll it to the second page in the viewDidAppear method.

Here is My UI.

[image]

Here is the line of code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0) animated: NO];
}
```

It is working fine on iPhone 6, but not working on iPhone 5.

I tried to switch to the `scrollRectToVisible` method. Always not working.

I'm using autolayout and size classes - compact/regular.

WHY is not working? Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the context of this code? because this can be happen for an animation incomplete or something like that

Comment: I edited the code above. The scroll view contains 3 pages, I'm trying simply to show the middle page every time the view appears.

Comment: try this `[self.statsScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0) animated: YES];` if this works let me know

Comment: There is a difference in screen resolution between iPhone 5 and 6, and the system may be scaling your views (or not scaling your views) to account for the difference.

Comment: @Reinier Melian, not working with animated:YES.

Comment: @Owen Hartnett, I also tried [self.statsScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated: YES];. Also notworking!

Comment: @Harrath hichem The way your device knows not to scale your views is to have a launch screen with a name such as "Default-568h@2x.png"

Comment: @Owen Hartnett Sorry, I didn't understand what do you mean. I'm using a Launch screen not a launch image.

Comment: This page might be helpful - scroll down to "IOS graphic asset requirements and options:" http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens

Comment: @Owen Hartnett What do you suggest me doing?

Comment: Compare the files in your app vs. the files listed in the article vis a vis indicating a screen resolution change.

Comment: @ Owen Hartnett I'm not getting your idea. I'm not using a default image for the splash screen. I'm using LaunchScreen.storyboard file.